# How can I reshape a list of numpy.ndarray (each numpy.ndarray is a 1*3 vector) into a 2-D Matrix , to be represented as an image?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing

I am working on a basic Image processing task - to conduct pixel based matrix operations given a matrix transformation formula. I am reading through pixel values (gives me a 1*3 tuple) from a (x,y) pixel location in the image and doing matrix operations using numpy, which returns numpy.ndarray's and finally I am required to store the transformed pixel values in a 2d matrix, each (x,y) co-ordinate storing a (1*3) vector of transformed pixel value.

```
def colortrans(im):
    #(X,Y,Z) = T + [M](*(RGB)(1*3 Vector) 
    # (X,Y,X) = (1*3 tuple) 
    # T = [0,128,128], (a 1*3 vector)
    # M = (3*3 Matrix) 
    # RGB = (1*3 Vector)

    pix = im.load()
    x,y = im.size 
    ycc = []
    #print(ycc.shape)
    m1 = np.array([[0],[128],[128]])
    print(type(m1))
    m2 = np.array([[0.299,0.587,0.114],[-0.168736,-0.331264,0.5],[0.5,-0.418688,-0.081312]])
    print(m2)
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y): 
            m = m1.T+np.dot(m2,np.array(pix[i,j]))
            #print(m.shape)
            #print(type(m))
            ycc.append(m)
    #ycc=np.array(ycc)
    print(ycc[1:5])
    mat_ycc = np.reshape(ycc,(x,y))   
    print(len(ycc))
    print (x, y)
    mat_ycc = np.reshape(ycc,(x,y))       
    return  mat_ycc
```

### I want something like this, a format which can be transformed into an image

```
[(180,128,128),(167,128,128) ... ]
```

### I get this(this format doesn't allow me to reshape as dims doesn't agree)

```
[array([[180., 128., 128.]]), array([[167., 128., 128.]]), array([[157., 128., 128.]]), array([[178.772   , 127.      , 128.162624]])]
```

### Error I get

```
len(ycc) = 409600
Image size  = 640*640
```

The error I get is :

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1228800 into shape (640,640)

Comment: Can you show the output of `ycc.shape`?

Answer (score 1):

You use the pixel count but each pixel constitutes of 3 values, so you should use
`mat_ycc = np.reshape(ycc,(x,y,3)) # note the ,3 part`

Comment: And one more thing; i don't know what your x,y values are but for reshape (in case of images) the parameters are (row, col, depth)

Answer (score 0):

Your way could work, but its way too complicated. Why don't you use blockproc as a little helper (I know this since I am in the same lecture)? You could write a simple function that transforms one pixel from RGB to YCbCr and then iterate with said helper over the matrix.

`your_matrix = blockproc(your_matrix, (1,3), your_color_transformation)`

You could also create a seperate Matrix via `numpy.zeros(size)` and then write your solutions into the right place. Here you can work with `(Y,Cb,Cr)` triples. Take every element from the image and process it seperately, create a triple and write it to the correct place.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are following a little complicated way. 
I have little suggestion:

- Create a U = np.zeroes(x,y,3)
- apply for loop on 2 dimensional image

  - rgb = select pixel value from all channels
  - ycc = apply the matrix op
  - U[i,j, :] = ycc